# Unable to import image in react app "Invalid or unexpected token"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

The issue is I get the error below when I run my Node/React app.
I had no issues importing images like this with `create-react-app`, but I want to do server side rendering so I followed a course on pluralsight which involves tooling the webpack and babel yourself.

> D:\Repo\WhiteTigerSSR\client\assets\img\clients\kier-logo.png:1 �PNG
>
> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
> at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
> at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
> at Object.newLoader [as .js] (D:\Repo\WhiteTigerSSR\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
> at Object. (D:\Repo\WhiteTigerSSR\client\client-page/index.js:3:1)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)

My NodeJS looks like this where I am doing server side rendering. I run babel-node server to run the app. Ignore the data API.

```
import React from 'react'
import express from 'express';
import {readFileSync} from 'fs'
import {renderToString} from 'react-dom/server'
import {App} from '../client/home-page/index'

const app = new express();

//serve client js file
app.use(express.static("dist"));

app.get("/data",async(_req,res) =>{
    
    res.json(data);
});

app.get('/', async (_req,res) => 
{
    const index = readFileSync("public/index.html","utf-8");
    //insert this server rendered string into our index file
    const rendered = renderToString(<App />);
    res.send(index.replace("{{rendered}}",rendered));

    //this was used for client side render
    //res.send(index); 
    // res.send(
    //     '<h1>React is Awesome</h1>'
    // )
});

app.listen(7777);
```

My webpack

```
const path = require('path');

process.env.BABEL_ENV = "development";

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",  
    target:'web',
    entry: {
        client: "./client/client.js",
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath:'/',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,"build")
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    /** can module be omitted for a simple project? No, it cannot. */
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                            '@babel/preset-react'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },   
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                  limit: 25000,
                },
            },   
            {
                test: /(\.css)$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },     
            {
                test: /\.(svg|jpeg|gif|png|jpg|webp)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: "[name].[ext]",
                        outputPath: "images"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }       
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "whitetiger_ssr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Marketing Website for White Tiger Ltd",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \no test specfied",
    "start": "babel-node server",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "Luke Perrin",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ionicons": "^5.3.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-popper": "^2.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/node": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1"
  }
}
```

In my react component I am importing the image like this

```
import kier from '../assets/img/clients/kier-logo.png'
```

And rendering like this..

```
render() {
        return (<div class="container p-4 client-container">
            <div class="client-background soft-corner">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column marketing-header soft-corner">
                    <h2 class="text-center center-item">Our Clients</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h3 class="text-center">Construction &amp; Industrial</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center d-flex"><img class="img-fluid align-self-center client-logo align-middle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-tooltip="" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse" src={kier} title="Kier Construction" alt="Kier Construction White Tiger Client" /></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center d-flex"><img class="img-fluid align-self-center client-logo" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-tooltip="" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse" src={bam} title="Bam Construction" alt="Luton Hoo White Tiger Client" /></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center d-flex"><img class="img-fluid align-self-center client-logo" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-tooltip="" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse" src={inter} title="Interserve Construction" alt="Redcoats Famehouse White Tiger Client" /></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center d-flex"><img class="img-fluid align-self-center client-logo" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-tooltip="" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse" src={taylor} title="Taylor Wimpey Construction" alt="Taylor Wimpey White Tiger Client" /></div>
            </div>
            <h3 class="text-center">Hotels &amp; Leisure</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 text-center d-flex"><img class="img-fluid align-self-center client-logo" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-tooltip="" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse" src={bw} title="Best Western Hotels" alt="Best Western White Tiger Client" /></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 text-center d-flex"><img class="img-fluid align-self-center client-logo" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-tooltip="" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse" src={luton} title="Luton Hoo Hotels" alt="Bupa Cromwell Hospital White Tiger Client" /></div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center d-flex"><img class="img-fluid align-self-center client-logo" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-tooltip="" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse" src={redcoats} title="Redcoats Hotel and Restaurant" alt="Interserve White Tiger Client" /></div>
            </div>
            <h3 class="text-center">Hospitals</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><img class="rounded img-fluid client-logo" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-tooltip="" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse" src={bupa} alt="Bupa Cromwell Hospital White TIger Client" title="Bupa – Cromwell Hospital London" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
```

This is the entry point in the app

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import {App} from './home-page/index'
import { clickhander } from '../shared/utility'

ReactDOM.hydrate(    
        <Router >
            <App />
        </Router>,    
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is the main body in index.html

```
<body>
        <div id="root">{{rendered}}</div>             
         <script src="client.js"></script>  
        <!-- comment out script for pure server rendered markup -->
    </body>
```

Comment: If you use that webpack config, the png file should be passed to url-loader or file-loader, which shouldn't produce that error. Could it be that you are not using the same webpack config for the server side rendering? Using import for image files only works if you use the proper webpack loader. If the runtime/build process tries to parse an image file like a regular javascript import, you could get an error like that. So the bug is caused by your webpack build process or config.

Comment: You dont need a seperate webpack for SSR , I am using all the loaders for images.. so its bizarre..

Comment: In you express app you do this: `import {App} from '../client/home-page/index'`. Presumably this file is already bundled by webpack?

Comment: No, I need to import it so it renders on the server. That is the entry point for React.

Comment: I referred to a youtube video.. :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwyQONeqRXA&t=610s   Seems this will solve my issue :)

Answer (score 1):

To resolve error "SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" regarding CSS on server side node.js install css-modules-transform with dev dependency

```
npm install css-modules-transform --save-dev
```

and at .bablerc add

```
{
"plugins": ["css-modules-transform"]
}
```

To resolve error "SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" regarding Files on server side node.js install babel-plugin-file-loader with dev dependency

```
npm install babel-plugin-file-loader --save-dev
```

and at .bablerc add

```
{
"plugins": ["css-modules-transform", "file-loader"]
}
```

finally run with babel-node

```
"scripts": {    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/server.js"}
```